# Join to get row matching minimum value of function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Gps] (
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Latitude] [decimal](9, 6) NOT NULL,
    [Longitude] [decimal](9, 6) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stops] (
    [StopName] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [StopLat] [decimal](9, 6) NOT NULL,
    [StopLon] [decimal](9, 6) NOT NULL
)
```

I would like to get the closest Stop for each Gps entry using a Haversine() scalar function that I wrote with this signature:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Haversine]
(
    @aLatitude  DECIMAL(9, 6),
    @aLongitude DECIMAL(9, 6),
    @bLatitude  DECIMAL(9, 6),
    @bLongitude DECIMAL(9, 6)
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(16, 6)
```

Example:

```
SELECT dbo.Haversine(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

I would like to get both the StopName as well as the result of the Haversine function.  How would I go about doing that efficiently?

Comment: Also, what do yo know about the distribution of the Gps and Stop values?  What's the highest expected distance between a Gps and it's closest stop? And do these tables have any indexes, or can you add them?

Comment: @RBarryYoung - SQL Server 2008 and I don't know the highest expected distance, and yes I can add indexes

Comment: I don't think that you can do much to optimize it if you can't tell us anything about the distribution of these things.

Comment: I actually don't have a working query yet — anything I've come up with so far is pretty terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select [Date],Latitude,Longitude,StopName,StopLat,StopLon, dbo.Haversine(Latitude,Longitude,StopLat,StopLon) as distance 
INTO #Distances 
from GPS,STOPS;

select * from #Distances d
join 
(
select [Date],min(distance) minDist from #Distances group by [Date]
) B on (d.[date]=B.[date]) and (d.distance=b.minDist);
```

Note that This query can select multiple rows for one GPS position if it has equal minimum distance to for example two STOPS. The main performance issue is in the first query (creating temporary #Distance table).

I think you should optimize this query through WHERE statement to reduce output table. For example you can set say maximum allowed distance from GPS position to any STOP position and add `WHERE dbo.Haversine(Latitude,Longitude,StopLat,StopLon)<MAX_ALLOWED_DISTANCE`.

Comment: This turned out to be the fastest query so far.  It looks like the remaining heavy lifting is the actual computation in my Haversine function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```
SELECT  Gps.*, Stops.*
FROM    Gps
JOIN    Stops   
        ON (dbo.Haversine(Latitude, Longitude, StopLat, StopLon) 
            = (SELECT MIN(dbo.Haversine(Latitude, Longitude, s2.StopLat, s2.StopLon))
                FROM    Stops As s2
            ) )
```

But it's sure not going to be fast.

---

Here's another way that should work:

```
;WITH
  cte As
(
    SELECT  Gps.*, Stops.*,
            dbo.Haversine(Latitude, Longitude, StopLat, StopLon) As distance,
            MIN(dbo.Haversine(Latitude, Longitude, StopLat, StopLon))
                    OVER(Partition By Latitude, Longitude)       As minDistance
    FROM    Gps
    CROSS JOIN
            Stops
)
SELECT  *, distance
FROM    cte
WHERE   distance = minDistance
```

Still just as slow though.

Comment: I get `Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.` as an error.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot actually test our suggestions for you since you have not given us the function definition, nor any test data.  However, I will post an alternate query that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are using SQL Server 2008, I recommend storing your GPS and STOP points using the built in `geography` data type, and using the built in `STDistance` function to measure the distance.

Comment: This turned out to be about an order of magnitude slower than just doing the math myself.  Thanks though, I learned something :)